# Need ideas with linked list in c#

Tags: c#

I need to add all professors from text file to linked list. This is how text file looks like:

```
Math;John Torpel;10
Physics;Tom Smith;40
...
```

So I wrote reading method:

```
public void ReadData(Container kon)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Sparta\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\WebSites\\WebSite4\\u22b.txt"))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
            string[] values = line.Split(';');
            ProjectWork temp = new ProjectWork(values[0], values[1], int.Parse(values[2]));
            list.AddToEnd(values[1]);
        }            
    }
}
```

And AddToEnd method:

```
public void AddToEnd(ProjectWork data)
{
    if(head == null)
    {
        head = new Node(data);
    }
    else
    {
        head.AddToEnd(data);
    }
}
```

I know that I did something wrong. What I need to change if I want to add professor name (values[1]) to linkedlist?

EDIT: LinkedList class:

```
 public class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    public void AddToEnd(ProjectWork data)
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(data);
        }
        else
        {
            head.AddToEnd(data);
        }
    }
```

I tried to do it from video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3svB0kM6f10

Comment: You are creating a new list for every line of text. Move the list creation out of the while loop to do it just once.

Comment: Your code and your file do not line up. You are splitting on a space which will result in just 2 values. values[0] = "Math;John" and values[1] = "Torpel;10". From your question, this does not appear to be what you want. You need to be splitting on ';' if your file truly looks like that.

Comment: Could you post more code from your LinkedList class ? It seems that you have infinite loop in AddToEnd function

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code is very confusing...you create a `LinkedList` for every line and throw it away immediatly? You split your lines by white space though they are `;` delimited? You try to pass a string (`values[1]`) to a method that needs a `ProjectWork` argument? `values[2]` should probably be `values[1]` and `values[3]` be `values[2]`? etc...

Comment: This is probably an exercise of how to implement a linked list, but just to be sure: there is already a ['LinkedList<T>'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the framework. Maybe you can take inspiration from it's source code.

Comment: @S.Nadezhnyy I edited my post and added LinkedList class

Comment: @GR2096 Why do you want to add `values[1]` to the list instead of the `ProjectWork temp` you just created a line before?

Comment: @RenéVogt I need to create list which contain all professors names. So I tought that I need to add only values[1]

Comment: It gets more and more confusing....you create a `LinkedList` which takes `ProjectWork` as elements, but you only want to add `string` elements? It sounds like you should take a step back and start with some c#/programming basics again. No offence intended, but I think there are too many misunderstandings here to solve this on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems.

1. You are declaring a new list in every iteration of your loop.
2. You are splitting using ' ' instead of ';'. Your file is delimited using';'.

It should be changed to this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Sparta\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\WebSites\\WebSite4\\u22b.txt"))
{
    string line = null;
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] values = line.Split(';');
        ProjectWork temp = new ProjectWork(values[0], values[1], int.Parse(values[2]));
        list.AddToEnd(temp);
    }            
}
```

Comment: This will not compile as `AddToEnd` does not take a string argument (maybe there's a cast operator from `string` to `ProjectWork`). If it compiles, it will throw exceptions because `values[3]` is out of range.

Comment: Indeed it will. I will edit. However, we do not know what values the `ProjectWork` constructor is looking for.

Comment: I'm very distracted so I forgot to fix code. Thanks. But how can I add values[1] to list?

Comment: We do know as OP already used it. The line should simply read `list.AddToEnd(temp)`.

Comment: I have assumed that the `ProjectWork` constructor accepts the 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns from the text file in that order and I have made edits to the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void ReadData(Container kon)
    {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Sparta\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\WebSites\\WebSite4\\u22b.txt"))
      {
     LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
                    string line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        string[] values = line.Split(';');

                        ProjectWork temp = new ProjectWork(values[0], values[1], int.Parse(values[2]));
                        list.AddToEnd(temp);
                     }
       }
    }

class ProjectWork
    {
        public string Lesson { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public ProjectWork(string _lesson, string _fullname, int _credits)
        {
            Lesson = _lesson;
            FullName = _fullname;
            Credits = _credits;
        }
    }
  class LinkedList
    {
        public void AddToEnd(ProjectWork data)
        {
           var myFullName =  data.FullName;
           var Lesson = data.Lesson;
           var Credits = data.Credits;

            //
        }
    }
```